# ViewChild vs Input/Output in Angular, any Disadvantages or capability difference?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am reading about Angular ViewChild and comparing to Input/Output parameters. Just curious if Viewchild has any disadvantages , or is unable to do something Input/Output can?

It seems ViewChild is the preferred route, since all parameters are now located in Typescript. This seems better than mixing/muddling into the html markup. Business/data logic parameters can now be in one place.

**ViewChild**

```
@ViewChild(AddressTypeDropdownComponent, { static: false }) child: AddressTypeDropdownComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Subscribe to the child component event
  this.child.addressTypeChange.subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
  });
}

someMethod() {
  // Set the input values of the child component
  this.child.addressTypeDefaultItem = someValue1;
  this.child.selectedAddressType = someValue2;
}
```

**Input/Output**

```
<app-address-type-dropdown 
    (addressTypeChange)="addressTypeChangeEvent($event)"
    [addressTypeDefaultItem]="someValue1"
    [selectedAddressType]="someValue2">
</app-address-type-dropdown>
```

Comment: If you use `@Input()` and `@Output()` thats totally okay for presentation component. You can use this presentation anywhere you want without any worries... as long as data are coming from smart component. So, for example... if you pass data to presentation component then it will display it or if you not passed any value it will simply not displaying anything. this scenario is very use-full when you can use same component for `add` and `edit` operation.

Comment: not sure why this question was voted down, seems like reasonable question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your preferences to be honest, I usually work with `ViewChild/ren` for dom manipulations similar to what we used to do with jQuery to change the native HTML element, and using `input/output` for data binding and controlling the state of a child component from the parent to keep him isolated and stateless.

example from angular docs - https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

you can see the ID property is being passed as an input for the pane component, while the visibility is managed from the parent.

now we could have changed it in case we had a button inside the `pane` that toggles the visibility and then you'll add an `output` to the `pane` component that emits the toggle state change to the parent, and still the parent will utilise the `viewChild` to change the child state.

In terms of tech issues and disadvantages, trying to set the child component properties by yourself isn't reactive and won't trigger Angular's change detection the same way `input/output` works (Angular watch those properties by default).

Testing such a component is hard since the child component isn't aware of his state and the changes the parent takes care of, you'll have to test them as one.

In general it's bad practice to change the component attributes this way since it'll break Angular's changeDetection and you'll need to manually manage it with `changeDetectorRef`

Comment: That's not really the purpose of ViewChild/ren, the answer you approved on the other question is not a practice you should use in Angular, it's break the entire concept of isolation and modularity.

Comment: @DanielNetzer: You have valid points +1 but can u provide example to support `trying to set the child component properties by yourself isn't reactive and won't trigger Angular's change detection` ? Take a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-components-viewchild?file=app%2Fperson.component.ts , the change in visibility is detected. I would like to see an example where the `ChangeDetection` is not triggered in case of `ViewChild`

Comment: `changeDetection` of angular is depends on to check properties-value is changed or not regardless of any `@Directive` or other way.. if you changed something from one state to other angular fire changeDetection to update state correctly on View. in `@ViewChild()` way we have to tell angular explicitly to detect change using `ChangeDetectionReference.detectChanges()` and in `@Input()` way angular is implicitly taken care of detectionChanges... so it will fire `onChanges()` life-cycle hook and we can get property value changes state of current, previous...

Comment: @ShashankVivek in 99% of my application i define `changeDetectionStrategy: onPush` so Angular won't check the entire tree, and then it fails.

Answer (score 9):

Adding on top of what has been answered. The use of `[ ]` and `( )` on `HTML` itself very descriptive to its implementation. The whole concept of Angular revolves around `HTML component` .

When you start breaking `DOM` into `components` , its re-usability is increased. When you use such components ( like we use [angular material](https://material.angular.io/) ), you want the user (who are importing it as libraries) to know what all params it takes as `Input` and what all params it emits as `Output`. You see such components in code and you immediately know what things are making it work.

With no proper representation, how can a user know ? [Take a look at this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nvvoybjbqrna?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-dynamic-columns-example.html)

**With @Input and @Output**:

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="addColumn()"> Add column </button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="removeColumn()"> Remove column </button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="shuffle()"> Shuffle </button>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>
```

**Without**

```
<button mat-raised-button #add> Add column </button>
<button mat-raised-button #remove> Remove column </button>
<button mat-raised-button #shuffle> Shuffle </button>

<table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>
```

**Which code would you prefer to read ?**

Also, how will you do simple events such as `(click)` , `(keyup)` or `[routerLink]`.

These things can be achieved by some work around, but would it be readable and dev friendly as it is now ?

Sometimes, we need to create segregated functionalities so that we can easily understand the reason of its existence in the code. It's applicable to all languages of Software

Comment: Nice explanation :) thnks

Comment: @katmanco : Happy to help :) Thanks for dropping the comment